# How was Shibo able to take her true form?

Tags: blame

In Blame!'s manga version, Shibo's first appearance was in chapter 9.2. She looks ugly and more like a walking corpse. (read from left to right)

[image]

But surprisingly, in chapter 9.3, she was able to take her true form. 
(read from left to right)

[image]

What did she do to re-make her physical form? On the Blame! [wiki](http://blame.wikia.com/wiki/Cibo), it is stated that she used backup data, but do they ever mention how they created the physical body using 'data'?